# I'm not getting the echo I want

Tags: php

I would like users who are NULL to be declared anonymous. For all others, the name should be displayed.

Problem: As I defined the request, all names in the guestbook that have ever written an entry in the guestbook are listed one after the other.

Like this - without brackets, I only set them to clarify the names: (test)(stak)(test)(uff)(test)(test)(Alf2016)(test)(test)(test)

```
while ($output = $query->fetch_object()) {
      echo '
      <b>Date:</b> ' . $output->date . ' <br>
      <b>Treff:</b> ' . $output->Treff . ' <br>
      <b>message:</b><br> ' . $output->message . ' <br>
      <b>user:</b><br> ' . !is_null($output->bn) ? $output->bn : 'Anonymous' . '<br><hr>'; 
  }
```

Comment: You should probably wrap your ternary in brackets so it doesn't mix with the rest of the string like this: `<br> '. (!is_null($output->bn) ? $output->bn : 'Anonymous') .'<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write ternary operators in a brackets, as in below-

```
   while ($output = $query->fetch_object()) {
            echo '<b>Date:</b> ' . $output->date . ' <br>'.
            '<b>Treff:</b> ' . $output->Treff . ' <br>'.
            '<b>message:</b><br> ' . $output->message . ' <br>'.
            '<b>user:</b><br> ' . (!is_null($output->bn) ? $output->bn : 'Anonymous' ). '<br><hr>';
        }
```